# Get WSL2 DNS to use Hosts DNS from DHCP

Tags: wsl-2

I'm trying to use WSL2 but the DNS isn't working, nothing resolves.  I've seen lots of articles about disabling resolv.conf generation and putting in a manual entry, however this won't work for me.  My workplace block the port DNS uses so I can't use 1.1.1.1 etc and I can't use the corporate DNS server IP as I want a solution that will work when I go home as well.

Is there a way for WSL2 to be able to use the DNS settings provided by the Hosts DHCP lease?  I've tried to change the virtual switch (WSL) in the Virtual Switch Manager to be External but it's still picking up an IP from the DHCP server.

Am I missing some Windows configuration or do I need some Linux Fu to change the config.  I was trying to get Podman-Desktop running and couldn't pull any images at work which is what started this off.

Answer (score 1):

Try **one** of these 2 maybe
1.
in your host, issue

```
ipconfig /all
```

and see the ip adrress for Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter. Put this IP in your /etc/resolv.conf

2.
convert to wsl 1. On your host command prompt,

```
wsl --set-version <distro_name> 1
wsl -d <disto_name>
ping google.com
```

if the ping resolve, convert back to wsl 2, copy the /etc/resolv.conf from wsl 1 to wsl 2

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, I however no longer need to do this as I just got work to build a linux box I can remote into instead.  I'm going to upvote it but since I can't really test I'm not going to mark it as the answer.